# Smooth button transition

Tags: html, css

I have a problem with an expanding container in which the button is, after hovering over the button. It vibrates, what makes it look really bad. Ideally fix would be with just CSS, because I am using these styles for form's submit button too.

Any suggestion on how to improve it?

[Link to codepen](http://codepen.io/kmarcink/pen/Bzovjw)

```
<div class="button-container">
  <a class="button" href="#">Text</a>
</div>


.button-container {
background: red;
}
.button {
background:#fff;
font-size:1em; 
padding:18px 26px; 
display:inline-block; 
margin:5px; 
border-radius:6px; 
border:solid rgba(0,0,0,0.2); 
border-width:1px 1px 5px; 
box-shadow:0 5px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.1), inset 0 0 2px rgba(255,255,255,0.3); 
cursor:pointer; 
user-select:none; 
transition:0.4s ease; 
min-width: 10em;
margin-top: 3px;
}

.button:hover {
margin-top: 0;; 
box-shadow:0 6px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.1), inset 0 0 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.4); 
border-bottom-width:8px; 
margin-top: 0px;
}

.button:active {  
box-shadow:0 2px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.1), inset 0 0 5px rgba(255,255,255,0.4); 
border-bottom-width:2px; 
transition:0.1s ease;
margin-top: 7px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you position your button absolute, it won't affect the containers size:

```
.button {
  position: absolute;
}
.button-container {
  height: 68px; /* ensure the container still has the same size */
}
```

Comment: I cannot specify the height of the container because it always be different. I want to use this button across the whole website.

Comment: @MarcinKilarski doesn't the button always have the same size? Then you may specificy `min-height`instead of `height`to ensure the container is always at least as high as the button (or higher, if other elements are present as well)

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because the height of `.button-container` is dependent on button height and margin and when you reduce margin on hover `.button-container` is effected. Another thing is the transition time is too high for this animation so there is vibration effect which is exactly because of big time

What you need to do is set a fix height to `.button-container` and reduce `0.4s` to `0.3s`

```css
.button-container {
  background: red;
  height:68px;
}
.button {
    background:#fff;
    font-size:1em; 
    padding:18px 26px; 
    display:inline-block; 
    margin:5px; 
    border-radius:6px; 
    border:solid rgba(0,0,0,0.2); 
    border-width:1px 1px 5px; 
    box-shadow:0 5px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.1), inset 0 0 2px rgba(255,255,255,0.3); 
    cursor:pointer; 
    user-select:none; 
    transition:margin ease 0.3s; 
    min-width: 10em;
    margin-top: 3px;
  
    }

    .button:hover {
    margin-top: 0;; 
    box-shadow:0 6px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.1), inset 0 0 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.4); 
    border-bottom-width:8px; 
    margin-top: 0px;
      
    }

    .button:active {  
    box-shadow:0 2px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.1), inset 0 0 5px rgba(255,255,255,0.4); 
    border-bottom-width:2px; 
    transition:0.1s ease;
    margin-top: 7px;
    }
```

```html
<div class="button-container">
  <a class="button" href="#">Text</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Can I do it without specifying the width of the container?

Comment: sorry, I meant without specifying the "height"

Answer (score 0):

on your transitions you need a property that needs animation:

```
  transition: all .2s linear;
```

In your case use `all` because you have multiple properties needing animation. I changed your easing to `linear`...I don't recall an `ease`. Refer to :https://jqueryui.com/easing/ . Sorry, I forgot to mention that jQuery only has 2 easings: linear and swing. If you want anything fancier, try [GSGD](http://gsgd.co.uk/sandbox/jquery/easing/) or [jQueryUI](http://jqueryui.com/download/#!version=1.11.4&components=1111000000000000000001000000000000000) (the jQuery link is a customized bundle which should be the minimal components needed to use all of the available easings.

http://codepen.io/zer00ne/pen/mEeaRm?editors=0100

Comment: Unfortunately, the container still vibrates http://codepen.io/kmarcink/pen/LZpqmd?editors=0100

Comment: One of your transitions is totally different than the other which wasn't in my demo, both transitions are `all` , I took the advice of Gaurav Aggarwal and gave the container a fixed height and MattDiMu and gave it a non-static position. I of course returned the transition values to match with `all`. http://codepen.io/zer00ne/pen/gMaEwb?editors=0100. I forgot to add that jQuery has only 2 easings available: swing and linear.

Answer (score 0):

You are causing [browser reflows](https://developers.google.com/speed/articles/reflow), which are expensive and change the layout on each animation step, causing the jerkyness and jitterness.

update the following in your style to reduce the reflow:

```css
.button{
   transition: margin-top 0.4s ease-in, border-width 0.4s linear, box-shadow 0.4s ease-in;
  }

.button:hover {
   margin-top: 0px;
   box-shadow:0 6px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.1), inset 0 0 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.4); 
   border-width:1px 1px 8px; 
  }
```

transtion property **ease-in** specifies a transition effect with a slow start where as **linear** specifies a transition effect with the same speed from start to end.

Comment: You can use **absolute** or **fixed** position to fix your problem, the transition of border-width is causing browser reflows. _flow the link to understand better and know more about browser reflows_